# Javascript regexp error (Invalid regular expression: /?/: Nothing to repeat)

Tags: javascript, regex, jsfiddle

What I'm making (if relevant) is a function to separate unicode characters that are different from each other (Eg. Numbers from letters).
As you may see from the title, it gives me an error of **Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /?/: Nothing to repeat**

I am definitely no expert on regular expressions. I haven't gotten around to studying it yet, and I have searched over stack over flow, but I didn't understand any answers, so it would be highly appreciated if you were to keep it simple for me, sorry for that inconvience.

The link is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ueb2bu9o/5/

```
useReg = new RegExp(getFirstSplit[i]);
```

Above is the code where the computer says the problem lies, but that may be incorrect. Also, for this little project of mine I am using Google Chrome and jsfiddle.net

If you need any more information just ask, and I will update this post

Comment: '?' character means "the previous character is optional." So everytime you encounter a '?' in your string, and do `RegExp('?')` it will fail. Why are you using a regex?

Comment: @lxe  , To see if the character used is inside the alphabet variable, and if not it will determine that it is junk.

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do precisely with your code?

Comment: If you read the first paragraph it explains what I'm trying to do... But I will try to explain it in more detail if that's what you wish. I am trying to separate numbers from any other character. And letters from characters such as **!@#$**. I will be using that information for a website, which I then will be multiplying and other things. It's simply for coding practices, as in practicing decoding something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get what you're trying to do, you're simply trying to go through the entire string, character by character, and sort them into categories of letter, number, or junk, right?

If that is the case, you don't even have to split the string at all — [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) will simply generate an array of matches from your string based on the regular expression you provide it, and you can manipulate the resulting array in any way you want. In this case, you want to join them into a string, using [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

The regular expressions you want to use for each category would be:

- `/[a-z]/gi`, meaning match all alphabets from A through Z
- `/[0-9]/gi`, meaning match all numberical characters from 0 through 9
- `/[^a-z0-9]/gi`, meaning characters that do not match the A-Z or 0-9 character set, i.e. whatever that is not selected in the first two.

Here's the JS code:

```
function manipulateString(string) {
    var letter,
        numbers,
        junk;

    letter = string.match(/[a-z]/gi).join('');
    numbers = string.match(/[0-0]/gi).join('');
    junk = string.match(/[^a-z0-9]/gi).join('');

    console.log(letter);
    console.log(numbers);
    console.log(junk);
}
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/ueb2bu9o/8/

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I need. Thanks a ton for your time :) . I will definitely have to remember to use .match more often.

Answer (score 0):

There are some characters like **? \ /** ... and others, which you cannot use directly, you should escape them using backslash **\**. Read more about it [**here**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
Error u see is because **?** is one of these special chars.

Answer (score 0):

`?` is a special character in regular expressions. It means that the character before it repeats either 0 or 1 times.

To search for literally ?, you have to put a backslash in front of it as in `'\\\\?'`